# Image resolutions to supply for adaptive iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, retina

While developing an iOS app I invested a lot of time in making everything adaptive (size-classes and so on). I have implemented an few image scrollers / photo galleries that are screen wide and zoomable. What is the best practice related to multi-screen image storage and exposure?

It is not a problem to store or generate on the fly, let's say, five different resolutions for every image and load the best resolution depending on network connection and screen size. I want to know what is recommended for this sort of diversity.

This is a (perhaps incomplete) list of all the possible image resolutions based on screen size:

- iPad landscape & portrait: **704px wide**
- iPad 2/3: **694px wide**
- iPad 1/2 landscape: **507px wide**
- iPad 1/2 portrait: **438px wide**
- iPhone 6+: **414px wide**
- iPhone 6: **375px wide**
- iPhone 4/5 + iPad split screen right-side: **320px wide**

All my images are square. So height equals width.

Do I include retina photos or should I use @1x for photos? Do I add extra pixels for the zooming (1.5x max)?

Answer (score 1):

This is are basically the current resolutions for iOS Devices.

[image]

Basically in the **retina devices** you need to provide **@2x images** if you want them to appear not pixelated. Also in the i**Phone 6 Plus and 6s Plus** you will need to provide **@3x images**.

In the following links you can find more information about it.

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-design-cheat-sheet-volume-2/
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide retina photos (@2x). If the user can zoom and you want that zooming to be not pixelated to you will need to add then bigger photos like for example @3x. Hope now is more clear :-)